# VS 2013 missing symbols (msvcr120.i386.pdb)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a very frustrating problem, I'm debugging my code, and for complete Call Stack I need to get symbols for msvcr120.dll (msvcr120.i386.pdb).

The thing is, that I can't get it.

- tried loading it from MS Symbols Servers, result:

> SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/msvcr120.i386.pdb/16F5E2EF340A453ABC8B8F67DC6FD8082/msvcr120.i386.pdb not found
>
> http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.

- tried downloading manualy symbols packages for various Windows versions from MS, downloaded aprox. 2GB, got symbols for msvcr from 90 to 110, and two 120 (from Win 10 package):

> msvcr120.i386.coresys.pdb
>
> msvcr120_clr0400.i386.pdb

So, is there a way to get "msvcr120.i386.pdb" ?

Comment: I have this pdb in my symbol cache, but it has a different hash. It is not exactly clear why your version is different, this tends to happen when you have an early release of that DLL.  Maybe one you got from using a beta version of Visual Studio.  If it actually is a beta and you somehow hacked around the expiration date then fuggedaboutit.  Otherwise consider applying [the updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2829760).

Comment: I'm working on VS 2013 with Update 5. I installed the update You linked, v4, but there is no change, still VS can't get symbols for msvcr120.dll from server.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the proper PDB for the file, you need to know which module is actually loaded.  If you create a crashdump (.DMP) of the program while running (which you can do with taskmanager), it should show you the exact file loaded, including it's full path.  You can also use a tool like dependency walker, which may do a better job at finding the full path.

Once you have the path, you can then specifically try to force-load symbols for that module by right-clicking, loading, and pointing to the exact file in question.  That should get the proper hash and load the correct PDB from the MS symbol store into your local cache.

What's likely happening is that the program you're running either has a manifest calling out a specific SxS version of the DLL, **OR** your program has crashed enough that Windows has placed it in "compatibility mode".  Either way, that means the program and VS are finding different versions of the DLL, thus the problem you're having.  You can also see this when your program crashes on a different machine than the one you're debugging on, especially if they're not both exactly in the same place for windows updates.

If you do dev work regularly, you should disable Windows automatically putting things into compatibility mode.  It will save you lots of headaches down the road.

Comment: How do you disable automatic compatibility mode? Internet turns up many results pertaining to microsoft word.

Comment: It's been many years since I've worked in windows.  But as I recall there was a way to disable compatibility mode for a specific EXE, and at the system level in general.  Both were doable via GUI or via registry. I'm relatively certain the Group Policy Editor was the GUI method.